# groupby and mean of subsets of columns in Python dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

If I have these 2 columns:

```
dat=[['yes','dog', 20,4,60,400],['yes','dog', 20,4,60,300],['yes','cat', 20,10,10,float('nan')]]
df_dat= pd.DataFrame(dat,columns = ["Time","animal", "val", "val2", "val3", "val4"])
```

I want to get a dataframe that uses groupby the "Time" and "animal". It then takes the means of combinations of the other columns. One subset is ["val","val3"] and ["val2","val4"].

Basically, something that takes means of the result of df_dat.groupby(["Time","animal"]).mean() for value column subsets

The output I'm looking for looks like (but in dataframe format):

```
[Index , 'val'/'val3','val2/val4'] 
[('yes','dog'),40,177]
[('yes','cat'),15,10]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Setup***

```
df = df_dat.groupby(['Time', 'animal']).mean()
subsets = [["val","val3"], ["val2","val4"]]
```

Using a dictionary comprehension and **`assign`**:

```
df.assign(**{'/'.join(cols): df[cols].mean(1) for cols in subsets})
```

```
             val  val2  val3   val4  val/val3  val2/val4
Time animal
yes  cat      20    10    10    NaN      15.0       10.0
     dog      20     4    60  350.0      40.0      177.0
```

If you only want the subset columns:

```
pd.DataFrame({'/'.join(cols): df[cols].mean(1) for cols in subsets})
```

```
             val/val3  val2/val4
Time animal
yes  cat         15.0       10.0
     dog         40.0      177.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need

```
ndf = df_dat.groupby(['Time', 'animal']).mean()
ndf['v1v3'], ndf['v2v4'] = ndf[['val', 'val3']].mean(1), ndf[['val2', 'val4']].mean(1)
```

Outputs

```
                val val2    val3    val4    v1v3    v2v4
Time    animal                      
yes     cat     20  10     10       NaN     15.0    10.0
        dog     20  4      60      350.0    40.0    177.0
```

Can, of course, just select the mean columns

```
ndf[['v1v3', 'v2v4']]

                v1v3    v2v4
Time    animal      
yes     cat     15.0    10.0
        dog     40.0    177.0
```

Comment: @AlexWarning Glad I could help :) Just as a side note, I noticed you accepted and unaccepted both answers several times. That's because in SO you can only accept one answer, but can upvote as many as you want. Take a look at [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to see how it works ;) happy coding !

Comment: lol, you noticed. They both worked and I was trying to give both the accepted before realizing you can only give 1 :(